# How can i make that if an item in a listBox is out of the bound on the right so it will move one line down?

Tags: c#

I have this code in a new Form where i add text to a textBox and then it's added to the listBox as item:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    public partial class ChangeLink : Form
    {


        public ChangeLink()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public string getText()
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }

        private void ChangeLink_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button1;
        } 

    }
}
```

And this is how i add the text to the listBox:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl = new ChangeLink();
            cl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            DialogResult dr = cl.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cl.Close();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label4.Text = cl.getText();
                mainUrl = cl.getText();
                if (!LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                {
                    newUrl = true;
                    KeysValuesUpdate();
                }
                else
                {
                    newUrl = false;
                    KeysValuesUpdate();
                }
                OptionsDB.set_changeWebSite(cl.getText());
                cl.Close();
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }
```

The problem is if the text was very long so in the right bound/border of the listBox the text of the item is cut. So to see it i want somehow to move it one line down or how much lines need to show the rest of the item text/name

So it will count as one item but if needed on some lines.

Update:

This is the part where i load the items to the listBox when im running my application:

```
private void ListBoxLoadKeys(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string FileName)
        {
            int t = listBox1.Width;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    int i = line.Count();
                    tokens = line.Split(',');
                    dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
                    string tt = tokens[1].Substring(t - tokens[1].Length);
                    data.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
                }

            }
            listBox1.DataSource = data;
        }
```

So variable t is the listBox Length(width)
And in this line i tried to calculate and get the text of tokens[1]"

```
string tt = tokens[1].Substring(t - tokens[1].Length);
```

But im getting an error startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Now i know the listBox Length(Width) but i don't want to put the text tokens[1] in a new line only if it's out of the bound out of the listbox Width(Length)

How can i fix and do this ?

Updated again:

Changed the code again now im trying first to check if each line in the variable data lngth is bigger then the variable t:

```
private void ListBoxLoadKeys(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string FileName)
        {
            int t = listBox1.Width;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    int i = line.Count();
                    tokens = line.Split(',');
                    dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
                    //string tt = tokens[1].Substring(t - tokens[1].Length);
                    data.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
                    if (data[i].Length > t)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("big");
                    }
                }

            }
            listBox1.DataSource = data;
        }

if (data[i].Length > t)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("big");
                        }
```

But im getting an error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: Maybe to add automatic somehow a groupBox or a grid or something like this for each item ?

Comment: If you know what you have specified as the length of the listBox, just use that to wrap the text using substring function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a standard listbox.  You need to create your own multi line listbox.  See this link for some guidance.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2695/An-editable-multi-line-listbox-for-NET

I've implemented this at work (ignoring the author's poor choice of colour scheme), and it works fine.

Comment: It's nice to see how a thing that can be done in 2 lines of XAML requires a horrible HACK in winforms.

Comment: Yep.  Awful isn't it.  I've had the misfortune of being on a WinForms project for the past 18 months and it's pretty bad.