# how to trigger winform button from elementhost viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a winform which display a view using elementhost. On my winform, I have a winform button which I would like to hide when a button on my view is clicked. Is there a way to achieve this? I just want to know how I can interact with the winform through my viewmodel for my view.

form.cs

```
VModel.DisableBtn += new ViewModel.EventHandler(_viewmodel_DisableExitFormButton); 

void _viewmodel_DisableExitFormButton()
{
    btnExitForm.Enabled = false;
}
```

xaml

```
<Button Name="btnSave" Command="{Binding SaveToDatabase}" />
```

viewmodel

```
private ViewModel _viewModel;

private ViewModel VModel
{
    get
    {
        if (_viewModel == null)
        {
            _viewModel = new ViewModel();
        }

        return _viewModel;
    }
    set
    {
        _viewModel = value;
    }
}

public delegate void EventHandler();
public event EventHandler DisableBtn;

public ICommand SaveToDatabase
{
    get
    {
        if (SaveToDatabase == null)
        {
            SaveToDatabase = new RelayCommand(p => SaveToDB());
        }

        return SaveToDatabase;
    }
}

private void SaveToDB()
{
    DiasbleExitFormBtn();
}

private void DisableExitFormBtn()
{
    // need to disable form button here
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that without resorting to a horrible hack. pretty much everything in winforms requires a horrible hack. winforms doesn't support the concept of a ViewModel. Anyways, post some code if you expect relevant answers here.

Comment: I want to be sure I understood your intention, your View (written in wpf?) Sits as ElementHost in Winfrom?

Comment: @HodayaShalom -- yes that's correct.

Comment: where is `_viewmodel` coming from in the winforms side?

Comment: Another question.. do you really need to keep the winforms stuff? It would be much better to trash it all and use pure WPF, which is cleanear and beautiful and does not require a hack for everything.

Comment: @HighCore -- that error has been resolved. it was because I was using the field instead of the property. Yes, I do need to keep the winform stuff because this is an existing app. Can you help me resolve the last part?

Comment: what's the last part?

Comment: @HighCore : Winforms being different from WPF does not mean everything you have to do is hack. It's just that you know WPF better than winforms. They're just different tools.

Comment: @Seb [**Really?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968377/how-can-i-make-that-if-an-item-in-a-listbox-is-out-of-the-bound-on-the-right-so/14968944#comment21016898_14968944) - [**Are you sure?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866064/windows-form-how-add-header-not-selectable-in-combobox-item-in-c/14866399#14866399) (Follow the links)

Comment: @HighCore Yes, I'm sure you can write clean code in most languages, in most frameworks. You can do data binding in winforms, which is the argument I hear most against winforms, but maybe I missed your point. Whatever, saying "that would require a horrible hack" in every post, answer and comment you make, is purely partisan argument, and not professional at all.

Comment: @HighCore Moreover, quoting your own answers and comments as a justification totally lacks of credibility and humility.

Comment: @Seb the first one is not an answer of mine. Its from somebody else. Also, please show me your winforms version of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710117/updating-ui-in-c-sharp-using-timer/14711744#14711744) so you can prove me that you can write clean code in winforms. Mostly the `<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Value}" x:Name="Rotation"/>` RotateTransform, I would like to see how winforms' supposed databinding deals with that.

Comment: @seb also, please show me how is the winforms' databinding version of these 2 Lines of XAML: `<CheckBox x:Name="chk"/>` `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk}"/>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24837/discussion-between-seb-and-highcore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinForm you can register to an event of the ViewModel that will play when pressing a button in your View, and then hide your button when this event happens.

For example:

ViewModel:

```
public delegate void SomeHandler();

public event SomeHandler YourEventName;
```

In your WinForm register to this event:

```
YourViewModel.YourEventName+=new YourViewModel.SomeHandler(Event_YourEventName);

      void Event_YourEventName()
        {
            //HIDE YOUR BUTTON
        }
```

Run the event by command when the button press in your view.

Hope this help

EDIT:

add this to your view model

```
   private void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        if (YourEventName!= null)
        {
            YourEventName();
        }
    }
```

and in your command call to this function

```
private void DisableExitFormBtn()
{
    OnButtonClicked();
}
```

**This should raise the event and run the function that sits in WinForm.**

Comment: when it reaches OnButtonClicked, the event name is null. I think it's because I'm using a "ViewModelLocator".

Comment: thank you. your suggestion worked. reason why i was having an issue is because my viewmodel in my winform instantiate a new viewmodel then once my view (xaml) load, it instantiate another new viewmodel. I just had to find a way to make sure they were both the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code to fire the event DisableBtn

```
 private void DisableExitFormBtn()
    {
        if(DisableBtn!=null)
          {
            EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
            DisableBtn(this, e);
          }
        // need to disable form button here
    }
```

Change the following :

```
public delegate void EventHandler(); // Comment this line or remove it
public event EventHandler DisableBtn;
```

Change this as :

```
void _viewmodel_DisableExitFormButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnExitForm.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: you're correct, it's not null but DisableBtn is still null. can you look at the code i've provided and tell me what else am i missing. do i need to do anything to the viewmodel constructor?

Comment: what happens at this line VModel.DisableBtn += new ViewModel.EventHandler(_viewmodel_DisableExitFormButton);

Comment: when I step through it, once it gets to that line, it goes to the property VModel and instantiate a new ViewModel. First going through all the fields I have then once that is done, goes to the constructor.

Comment: once it goes to the next line without stepping thru, is DisableBtn null?

Comment: I've notice that once it goes to the next line, DisableBtn on this line VModel.DisableBtn += new ViewModel.EventHandler(_viewmodel_DisableExitFormButton) is not null. It is null however in the viewmodel inside the method private void DisableExitFormBtn() as your code above.

Comment: I have made some changes, I am not exactly sure how a delegate with same name as EventHandler and different signature would behave.

Comment: no avail. I'm wondering if it's because I have a viewmodellocator used for my xaml. could be the issue as to why it's not null the first time and then once it's in the xaml, it's null since it is instantiating a new one.